# Can't put a horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a horizontal scroll and falling flat, [**here is the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryPdK/3/)

please help me find what i'm doing wrong

edit

here is the markup

```
<table >
      <tr>
         <td style="width:300px;">
         <div style="width:300px;overflow-x:scroll !important;">
              <table style="width:100:float:left!important;">                          <caption>2011</caption>
                             <td class="top">Brand</td>      
                             <td class="top">Target</td>

                            <tr>
                                 <td>ABC</td>
                                 <td>22</td>

                            </tr>    
              </table>
            <table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table>  
<table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table> 
<table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table>  
<table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table>               
        </div>
        </td>          
     </tr>             
</table>  
​
```

here are the screen shot of current and the desired output

[image]

Comment: Please just post your code here, for ease of everyon else and in case you you change it later.. the code still remains with your question

Comment: @BugFinder just added the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryPdK/8/
change this

```
<div style="width:500px">
```

width to something huge, eg

```
<div style="width:9999px">
```

so that it can accommodate many such tables and works the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the scroll div less width then the inner table like this, [Demo available here JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4EW6/1/)

```
<table style="width:400px" >
      <tr>
         <td style="width:300px;">
         <div style="width:300px;overflow-x:scroll !important;">
              <table style="width:350px">                          <caption>2011</caption>
                             <td class="top">Brand</td>      
                             <td class="top">Target</td>

                            <tr>
                                 <td>ABC</td>
                                 <td>22</td>

                            </tr>    
              </table>
            <table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table>  
<table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table> 
<table style="width:100px;float:left!important;">                        <caption>2012</caption>
                             <td>Brand</td>     
                             <td>Target</td>
                             <tr>
                                <td>bnc</td>
                                 <td>22</td>                                
                             </tr>   
             </table>              
        </div>
        </td>          
     </tr>             
</table>  
​
```

Comment: tnx for the reply, can you please hava a look at the screenshot i have uploaded, how can i get the tables in one line

Comment: You are welcome, There could be many ways this is one of them http://jsfiddle.net/6A8D6/

Comment: @John - you have an odd layout nesting tables within tables, but if you want to keep that approach and achieve your screen shot then remove the `300px` fixed widths and add `float: left` to all of your tables (it is currently missing from the first nested table)

Answer (score 2):

Acoording to your desired view, you can check this fiddle need all tables floated and added one more DIV containing all tables

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chanduzalte/ryPdK/6/) having those changes.

Comment: tnx for your time, but i put another table inside the div it goes down, http://jsfiddle.net/ryPdK/8/ the tables inside the div are generated dynamically

Comment: How much max number of table are  generated dynamically ? so according that set min-width for that div